# Which Design Pattern can I use?

Tags: java, design-patterns

I like to realize the following scenario. (example)

I have 3 Classes:

1. Controller
2. Apple
3. Car

```
public class Apple implements IBonus {
    public String name;
    public String weight;
}


public class Car implements IBonus{
    public String brand;
    public String vmax;
    public String power;
}

public class Controller {
    public List<String> values;

    public void doWork(IBonus bonusObject){
       if(bonusObject instanceOf Car){
          Car c = (Car)bonusObject;
          values.add(c.brand);
          values.add(c.vmax);
          values.add(c.power);
       }
       if(bonusObject instanceOf Apple){
          Apple a = (Apple)bonusObject;
          values.add(a.name);
          values.add(a.weight);
       }
    }
}
```

Now, I have a lot of Classes like apple and car. And there is also the possibility that some variables of each class will be changed, added or removed in the near future.
This will mean that I always have to adjust the code in the controller class.

Does anyone know a suitable pattern?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You don't need any pattern for this. Just plain old polymorphism:

```
public interface IBonus {
    void fillStringList(List<String> values);
}
...

public void doWork(IBonus bonusObject){
   bonusObject.fillStringList(values);
}
```

Comment: I'll bet you they have a name for this one, too! Template method, perhaps?

Comment: Nope. A template method is a method that does some complex stuff by implementing the common parts, and delegating specific parts to methods overridden in subclasses. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Template_method_pattern. I would just call this polymorphism.

Comment: So if `doWork` does some complex stuff by implementing the common parts and delegates to `fillStringList` for the subclass-specific details?

Comment: There is no inheritance here. Just an object using another object of some interface type, without caring about the concrete type of the used object. And the concrete implementations of the interface each implementing the method in their own way. It's the basic polymorphism concept. So basic that it doesn't have a pattern name. It's what you do all the time when calling an interface method or a superclass method.

Comment: Your description "so basic..." fits half of the patterns that have a name :) In this case the specific collaboration between the Controller and the model classes (controller owns the collection, the interface methods fill it) is a certain pattern that can be extracted and its complexity is already about at the level of the Template.

Answer (score 4):

EDIT: Design pattern "Visitor".

Change your iBonus interface to add a method:

```
void add(List<String> values);
```

Have the Controller instead do

```
bonusObject.add(values);
```

This way you delegate the specific task (adding an object to 'values') to the specific implementation.

Basically whenever you find yourself writing code like the above (if instanceof or switch()) you should instead consider delegating the task to an abstract method.

You may want to consider "double dispatch" aka. "Visitor"

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visitor_pattern

The Wikipedia version is very generic, and splits out the "Visitor" logic (adding to the list) into a seperate class. In the below version the "Bonus" objects play that part, and the double dispatch structure is used instead.

In that scenario you have two interfaces: One for the bonus object, and one for the controller. The bonus object has a method called

```
void visit(Controller c);
```

The controller will then invoke the bonus object thus:

```
bonusObjecv.visit(this);
```

The purpose of "Visitor" is largely to let you vary the implementations independant of each other. It is a more generic version of the simple, polymorphic solution. Instead of using a generic class such as List you use the Controller interface. That way you make the interaction between controller and visited object explicit.

Answer (score 2):

You could add a method:

```
public List<String> getValues();
```

to your IBonus interface and just use the following in doWork:

```
values.addAll(bonusObject.getValues());
```

Each IBonus type will then need to implement how to create the list.

Answer (score -2):

I think Factory pattern will suit in this condition.

[Factory pattern Example](http://javapapers.com/design-patterns/abstract-factory-pattern/)